# How to solve "Can't find DLL entry point [function] in [dll]"?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, office365, unmanagedexports

I am working in a x64 Class Library made in .NET framework 4.7.2.

This code is going to be used in MS Access with Office365, and I need to load the library into the database.

Below is the code I use to reference the dll, it is important to know that this code snippet is located in a Class Module:

```
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal GetModuleHandle As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function myFunction Lib "Path\To\dll.dll" () As Object
```

Of course, the Class Module has a function which declares an object to be able to call all the other functions inside the class, here is the code:

```
Private Function DM() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    If dmObject Is Nothing Then
        'load from the dll
        hLibModuleID = LoadLibrary("Path\to\dll.dll")
        'Debug.Print hLibModuleID
        
        Set dmObject = myFunction()
        'Debug.Print dmObject
    End If
    
    Set DM = dmObject
End Function
```

My problem comes in the line `Set dmObject = myFunction()`, because `myFunction()` returns `Nothing` and it throws the following error:

[image]

I am using MS Access x64 so obviously the dll is compiled in the corresponding platform target.

I have also installed the `NuGet Package` called `UnmanagedExports` which allows me to add the following reference:

```
using RGiescke.DllExport;
```

And its attribute:

```
[DllExport]
```

If it can help, my `Visual Studio` project uses `PackageReference` instead of the old `Packages.config` file.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need an explicit `LoadLibrary` call. Have you used Dependency Walker or simialr tool to check the function is actually being exported correctly?

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing is shown when I select the file.

Comment: Then `UnmanagedExports` isn't building properly. Exactly why, we cannot see. You will need to check the docs and make sure it's installed correctly.

Comment: It is exactly what I was thinking, I will try to search about UnmanagedExports and if I find something interesting or I can solve the issue by myself I will update the question.

Comment: The error 453 "Can't find DLL entry point" has nothing to do with the function returning Nothing. It is not returning Nothing, it is not being called in the first place, because it is not there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After racking my barin for hours and hours, I found the solution.

The problem was in the way I was returning my object in `MyFunction()`, so, it was not a problem of `VBA` code, it was from `C#`.

I was doing the following:

```
MyClass object = new MyClass(); 
return object;
```

The problem was that when I am declaring the variable `object`, I cannot set it directly to `MyClass`, and I did this:

```
var object = new MyClass();
```

If I declare the variable as `var` it works perfect.

It was an easy to solve problem, but I spent lots of hours on it.

At least I learnt something new ;)

Comment: `MyClass object = new MyClass();` and `var object = new MyClass();` are identical in the type of the variable `object` that they create. Neither could result in the error 453 in VBA that you quote. Apparently all you did was recompiling the library, as you were using the old version from VBA that did not have the function in it.

Comment: I did not ONLY recompile (of course I did, but not only this). This is not true, at least for my problem. The only way to solve that I found was changing what I said.

Comment: The meaning of the `var` does not change depending on the problem. That change in the code did absolutely nothing. Apparently the recompilation did. The claim that `when I am declaring the variable object, I cannot set it directly to MyClass` is explicitly false, as having declared a variable as `MyClass`, you absolutely can assign a `new MyClass()` to it.

Comment: In my case, again, it was the solution, that was not the first thing I tried, and changing it, I could do it. That was not just for recompile. I am not trying to make you understand it because you did not have the problem, but it was my solution, what it worked for me. Anything else to say.

Comment: It was not the solution in your case. Claiming that it was only confuses the future readers. With the same justification you can say that the problem was that there was a comment in your code, `// Creating an object here`, and after you changed that comment to `// Creating a var here`, your code was fixed. It was not the change in the comment that fixed it. Exactly what that you did that fixed it, we don't know, and the only guess I have is that it was the recompilation. What we know is that it wasn't changing `MyClass object` to `var object`.

Comment: Ok, you have the reason.